# Windows phone7 Interface design in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In my Windows phone7 silverlight Application I have several textblock pairs to display some dynamic data in run time.

For example

```
Name:     TextBlock[Dynamically_loading_Name]   <-----------------(A)
Address:  TextBlock[Dynamically_loading_Asddress]  <--------------(B)
Phone:    TextBlock[Dynamically_loading_Phone]  <-----------------(C)
```

Since I don't know how long the dynamic data, to The textBlocks(A, B, C), I have gave properties Height=Auto and TextWrapping=Wrap.

The problem is when data loaded to the A,B,C textBlocks they are overlapping.If I can give the margin to relative to the other textBlock I think it will be ok. By dafault margin to counts from the top of the page.

I added StackPanels to each row and Gave stackPanel height property=Auto Also. Still it overlaps when the upper record is too lengthy.

If Someone can help me to overcome this issue it a big help. Thanks

Edits................................................................

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,20,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441">
            <TextBlock Height="30" Name="txt_Title" Text="Title:" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="item_Title" Text="TextBlock" Width="330" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,83,0,0" Name="stackPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441">
            <TextBlock Height="30" Name="txt_Link" Text="Link:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="item_Link" Text="TextBlock" Width="306" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,146,8,0" Name="stackPanel3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="439">
            <TextBlock Height="30" Name="txt_Description" Text="Description:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="item_Description" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="305" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,209,0,0" Name="stackPanel4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="439">
            <TextBlock Height="30" Name="txt_Comment" Text="Comment:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="item_Comment" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="305" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,272,0,0" Name="stackPanel5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444">
            <TextBlock Height="30" Name="txt_PubDate" Text="Published_Date:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="item_PubDate" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="307" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,335,0,239" Name="stackPanel6" Width="444">
            <TextBlock Height="30" Name="txt_Creator" Text="Creator: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="item_creator" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="305" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need is a `Grid`. Just need to make the `Heights` auto sized. Also, you might want to always apply a style to your `TextBlock` to have consistant margins.

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Title" Text="Title:" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" /> 
    <TextBlock x:Name="item_Title" Text="This is a very long title and I have no idea how long it will be" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Link" Text="Link:" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="item_Link" Text="This could be long too..." TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Description" Text="Description:" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="item_Description" Text="This will be very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long..." TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Comment" Text="Comment:" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="item_Comment" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_PubDate" Text="Published_Date:" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="item_PubDate" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Creator" Text="Creator: " Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="item_creator" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" /> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this forum post can help you out. Basically try setting MaxWidth property of the stackpanel if everything else fails ;)

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/58227.aspx/1?Why+TextBlock+doesn+t+wrap+even+I+set+TextWrapping+to+Wrap+

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my textWraping working fine. Problem is when the text is too long as it goes to next line to display it overlaps with the one that is there below it.

Comment: Can you please edit and show some sample code so that I can reproduce the problem and help you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use one grid cell and several margins for all items. If you use a StackPanel instead of the Grid, the arrangement should be fine.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  </StackPanel>

  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

**Edit:**

I made a sample project which looks good for me, but I'm not sure if I really got your problem. The first title does not wrap as it has a fixed height, but the second does as the height isn't set. All Stackpanels adjust their sizes as they should.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Height="30" Width="90" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Title does not wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock Width="330" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Width="90" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Title wraps" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock Width="330" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi MAtthiasG, Within the stackpanel anything doesn't overlap. When dynamic text in an upperstack panel too lengthy, the upper stackpanel overlaps with the bottom one. In my case when the text loads to Name="item_Title" is too lengthy stckpanel1 and stackpanel2 Overlaps

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't have expected this behavior. I will try this in a small sample project.

Comment: I edited my post adding a sample code that seems to work for me. I'm just not sure, if I really got your problem, but as it looks good for me, please have a look at it.

Comment: Hi MAtthiasG, When we statically define the value of the textblock itsfine. We can arrange it. The problem occurs when a text dynamically load to the textblock in runtime. Because it can last for 2 lines 3 or 5 or any according to the length. if we can give the margin top value of the bottom stackpanel a relavant to the top stackpanel this won't occur. by default margin top value count from top of the page and thts the problem.

Comment: Even when setting the long text after a button click the layout is adjusted as it should in my project. How is it set in your case?